# Communicating between fragments in Android

Tags: android, interface, fragment

Based on the example from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html I tried to reproduce the communication between two fragments which are sub fragments of a larger fragment.

In the example, **AB activity** contains A fragment and B fragment. But I am trying to achieve the same but in my case  **AB Fragment** contains A fragment and B fragment.

The problem is the overridden method in the AB Fragment never gets called. Does this not work because the containing component is a Fragment and not a Activity like in the example? Am I missing out something here?

Comment: could You provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to `onClick()` or some other `onSomething()` handler, then these always get called in the `Activity` class, not the fragment. So in the example you linked, the `onArticleSelected()` must remain in the `Activity`, even if you have nested fragments.

To pass info on to the fragment, you have a few options. One, you can keep a reference to the fragment within the activity. This might be lost if your activity recreates (settings event for example).

The second and better way would be to tag your fragments, and then use `findFragmentByTag`.

When you add your fragment (notice the parameter "my_fragment" which is the tag I gave to the fragment):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "my_fragment").commit();
```

Or when you replace one fragment with another:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "my_fragment").comit();
```

Then, when you want to do something in the fragment from within your `onArticleSelected` of the activity:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment");
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.articleSelected(articleId);
}
```

Comment: But again (assuming  onArticleSelected() is in the activity)How do I communicate from the activity to the other nested fragment? Instantiating the Fragment aint the right way I guess. I need to access the methods of the nested fragment through the already instantiated reference

Comment: Just for records, adding that interfaces passing on the control and  holding on to the fragment reference would be it... Although not sure how much of an effective solution this is considering the fact that frag reference is involed

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an `Interface` to communicate between fragments. It is the safest way to do so.